# Create multiple records using single form (Not nested attributes)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-4

In my application I have a Thought model which has content and author attributes.

I want to create multiple thoughts at once using new form. But this is not a case of nested forms as i am not using any associated models.

Please suggest some solution.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try with the below solution

In your View File

```
<%= form_tag your_action_path do %>
  <% 4.times do |i|%>
    Content : <%= text_area_tag :thought_content, "", :name => "thoughts[][content]" %>
    Author : <%= text_field_tag :thought_author, "", :name => "thoughts[][author]" %>
  <% end %>
  <%= submit_tag "Submit" %>
<% end %>
```

Controller Code:

```
def your_action
  params[:thoughts].each do |thought_params|
    Thought.create(thought_params)
  end
  ###
  #Any further code#
  ###
end
```

Hope it works for you :)

Answer (score 4):

In frontend you can use jquery onClick function to add fields for more thoughts ie you can add a link called "add more" & create a jquery function to add fields for another thought in the same form with dynamic field names & in the backend you can use

```
@thoughts = Thought.create([{ author: 'Chicago', content: 'content' }, { author: 'Chicago', content: 'content' }, .......])
```

to create multiple entries in one go.

Comment: Nice one liner solution!