# Create multiple records at once ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

This seemed fairly straightforward, but is proving not to be.

I have two models: Authors and Books. Authors has_many books, books belong_to authors.  I'd like to be able to add many books in a single form with different authors and information for each.

```
class BooksController < ApplicationController

def new
 @books = []
  5.times do
    @books << Book.new
  end
end
```

I'm not sure if that's the correct way to form the controller. The view is as follows:

```
<%= form_tag(books_path(@books)) %>
 <% @books.each do |book| %>
  <%= text_field_tag(:title) %>
  <%= text_field_tag(:author) %>
  <%= text_field_tag(:pages) %>
 <% end %>
<%= submit_tag("Submit") %>
```

That's as far as I've gotten, as I can't get the @books to end up in my params, so I haven't gotten to trying the create method yet. All i'm getting is the :title, :author and :pages of the last record, and they aren't even in a book param.

Comment: You're after the `fields_for` helper.

Answer (score 2):

`form_tag` doesn't know your model object. So it won't wrap your params under the appropriate key. You should instead use `form_for` to save yourself the trouble of constructing the params.

In order to create associated objects you can use `accepts_nested_attributes_for`.

In order to create multiple objects you need to [send their params to your controller in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27939990/4720244). But I'd suggest you save single record only. You code would be cleaner and you can take advantage of Rails form helpers such as `form_for` and `fields_for` instead of constructing the HTML code by hand.

Comment: What would be the proper way to construct with `form_for`? The @books local variable is an array, so I'm not sure how it works with that method

Comment: If you want to stick with @books and creating multiple records in one form, you'll probably be stuck with form_tag and constructing HTML manually, like the linked solution. But I think it's better to create one record in one form. The code is cleaner, and the user experience is probably better. You can always use ajax if you want to allow users to continue creating records without being redirected.

Comment: Yea, the goal was to create multiple records with one form to make it quicker. The app already has a form for adding one, but wanted to explore adding a form that allows for a bulk-style import.